# How does one evaluate a prediction confidence for an SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

For an SVM classifier, how can I get the confidence of each prediction ? I thought of adding a "unknown" class, but I don't quite see how to do it ( what values ?)

While theory is highly appreciated, I would be glad if you can give me hint(s) on how to do it in scikit-learn.

Comment: https://event.pwizard.com/upload/account_163/file/Jonathan%20Yefenof.pdf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502803/svm-classification-confidence-interval

Comment: That is, you can do it by bootstrapping or cross-validation.